Get all parent with an active child node in fancytree
The set up I want to achieve is to highlight all parents text with changing its text color if there are any active child or grandchild node. If there are no other active child all will be in their default text color.
select: function(event, data) {
  // child node selected
  if ( $(data.node.span).parents(".fancytree-has-children").find(".fancytree-selected").length ) {
    $(data.node.span).parents(".fancytree-has-children").find(".fancytree-title").css("color", "red");
  }
  else {
    $(data.node.span).parents(".fancytree-has-children").find(".fancytree-title").css("color", "gray");
  }

  // parent is selected
  
}

The complication is when there are child or parent node that is previously selected.
I tried it using jQuery by dom minipulation on span tag for class indicators.

Can you also share how the html looks like? Working fiddle/playground would be great as well.

Please create a minimal reproducible example
